# Why would a dialog erase its content without refreshing?

Tags: windows, mfc

I'm having this very strange problem where a window seems to be erasing its content and not redrawing it after erasing it.  This dialog is derived from `CDHtmlDialog`, which I think is part of the problem.  There is some sort of non-deterministic code execution happening resulting in some code being executed prior to others in certain cases and the opposite in others.

Message handlers that are involved are:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCalcDrillDownDlg, CDHtmlDialog)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP(CCalcDrillDownDlg, CDHtmlDialog)
     ON_EVENT(CCalcDrillDownDlg, AFX_IDC_BROWSER, 250 /* BeforeNavigate2 */, _OnBeforeNavigate2b, VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PBOOL)
END_EVENTSINK_MAP()
```

The `OnInitDialog()` function is as follows:

```
BOOL CCalcDrillDownDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    SetHostFlags(DOCHOSTUIFLAG_FLAT_SCROLLBAR);

    CDHtmlDialog::OnInitDialog(); // << will eventually call _OnBeforeNavigate2b()

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    LoadFromResource(IDR_CALC_DRILLDOWN); // << will eventually call _OnBeforeNavigate2b()
    CString title = getStr2Ptr(22574);
    SetWindowText(title);
    ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

This is the `OnPaint()` function:

```
void CCalcDrillDownDlg::OnPaint() 
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, (WPARAM) dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDHtmlDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}
```

I've not put the contents of the `_OnBeforeNavigate2b()` function as it appears not to have anything to do with the redrawing system.

So what appears to happen is that sometimes, the dialog contents will be painted somehow prior to calling `CCalcDrillDownDlg::OnPaint()`.  If this happens, then the call to `CDHtmlDialog::OnPaint()` will wipe the contents off the window.

Other times, the contents are not painted on the window prior to calling `CCalcDrillDownDlg::OnPaint()`.  If this happens, then the call to `CDHtmlDialog::OnPaint()` will probably still wipe the contents off the window, which hasn't been painted yet, and then sometime after the call to `CCalcDrillDownDlg::OnPaint()`, it gets redrawn.

Spy++ doesn't capture any messages when the system properly redraws the window, so I've removed the messages generated from this question.

Does anyone have any idea as to how the redrawing is getting done and why the order gets foobarred sometimes?

## Edit

Here is the contents of the `IDR_CALC_DRILLDOWN` resource:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Calculation Drilldown</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { overflow-y: auto; font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 90%; }

        a:link { color: black; }
        a:visited { color: black; }
        table { border-collapse: collapse; }

        tr.runcache td { background-color: #B5B5B5; color: black; }
        tr.runcache td a:link { color: black; }
        tr.runcache td a:visited { color: black; }

        tr.tracker td { background-color: white; color: black; }
        tr.tracker td a:link { color: black; }
        tr.tracker td a:visited { color: black; }

        td.numericvalue { text-align: right; }

        tr.paramTitle td { background-color: #4A4A4A; color: white; }

        tr.resultTitle td { background-color: #4A4A4A; color: white; }
        tr.resultTitle td a:link { color: white; }
        tr.resultTitle td a:visited { color: white; }

        tr.param td { background-color: white; color: black; }
        tr.param td a:link { color: black; }
        tr.param td a:visited { color: black; }

        span.selection { background-color: #EBEBEB; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calculation"></div>
    <div id="details" style="padding-left: 0.1in; display: none;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Edit #2

Further investigation seems to show that the CDHtmlDialog class (or a base class thereof) will draw the window, irrespective of if my `CCalcDrillDownDlg::OnPaint()` calls `CDHtmlDialog::OnPaint()` or not, which is just weird and not intuitive. :(

Also, it seems that this is possibly threading related, as this seems to be dependant on how long it takes to render the window.  If it takes a short time, it displays fine.  If it takes a half a second or more, it screws up.

For the moment, I'm using a workaround where I have a `m_bRepaint` flag in the class which is initially set to `true`.  Upon calling `CCalcDrillDownDlg::OnPaint()` and it is not iconic, I check the flag and force a resize.  This is not optimal as it causes an initial flicker, but it at least it makes sure that the window's contents are drawn.

```
    if (!m_bRepaint)
    {
        CDHtmlDialog::OnPaint();
    }
    else
    {
        CRect winRect;
        GetWindowRect(&winRect);
        SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, winRect.Width() - 1, winRect.Height(), SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
        SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, winRect.Width()    , winRect.Height(), SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
        m_bRepaint = false;
    }
```

Using `Invalidate()` does not work.  I have to resize it to something other than it's current size and resize it back.

This `CDHtmlDialog` class is a PITA to work with and I wouldn't recommend anybody use it if they have a choice.

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can only guess.

Comment: @theB, if I could do that, I'd prolly be done. Some possible suggestions would be nice.

Comment: If you can't provide a [mcve], please provide the relevant snippet of code.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, what would be considered relevant in this case? The message handlers that the class is handling?

Comment: Seeing as I don't know what your code looks like, I don't know.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes,  unfortunately, it's not my code. I'll try and post something before the end of the weekend.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "refreshing". Show a picture of the dialog, what it looks like and what it should look like. Show any overrides you have added for `ON_WM_XXX` messages

Comment: Thanks for the comments to make this a better post.  If there are any more suggestions that would help to reopen this question, please comment as to what that would be.  Otherwise, please vote to reopen.  Thanks.

Comment: I think I had a similar problem, I got around it by putting `m_strCurrentUrl = "filepath.htm"` in `CDHtmlDialog` constructor.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, I'm not sure what you were attempting, but adding stuff to the source of the MFC library sounds like it could get sketchy fast.

Comment: I mean you can add that to your own constructor, for example `CMyDHtmlDialog` but never mind, I don't know how to implement `LoadFromResource`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, so you meant to add to the derived class.  I tried your suggestion, but it didn't do anything.  Not sure what you mean by _"I don't know how to implement `LoadFromResource`"_.

Comment: You should try that again. Put `m_strCurrentUrl = "filepath.htm"` in `CCalcDrillDownDlg` constructor without calling `LoadFromResource` and without overriding other functions.

Comment: If you remove all your code and just use the base class without changes, do you still get the problem?

Comment: @Neil, if I remove my code, that would mean that it won't show anything, wouldn't it?  So how would I know if I have the same problem?

Comment: @Adrian I was trying to think of a way that you could remove your code from the problem.  It's entirely possible you've found a bug with CDHtmlDialog, so removing your code from the equation should do that.  Of course, it could be your HTML that is the problem.  Maybe instead of LoadFromResource, you LoadFromUrl("google.com")

Comment: Is this *all* of your code? You have overridden/handled only the `OnInitDIalog` and `OnPaint` functions for this dialog and all of its parent classes? Because your problem sounds like some code is obtaining a DC and drawing directly into it, instead of drawing in response to a paint event. **Should we expect to reproduce your problem using just the code shown in the question?**

Comment: Damn it.  I'm not sure what happened, but I cannot reproduce the issue.  I was reproducing it easily, but now, for some reason, it is not happening again. >:(  Random bugs like this really piss me off!  >:(

Comment: @CodyGray, I've stated the issue and the overrides I've done.  Seems that the issue has vanished from my simple test case.  At least this is all under source control so I can be assured that nothing has changed after all the mods I've done to try and track down the problem.

Comment: At least my more complex reproduction steps still cause this to happen. Gah! PITA!!  So @CodyGray, in response to your question **Should we expect to reproduce your problem using just the code shown in the question?**: maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it would seem that this is caused by the windows message queue not being deterministic, so it would seem that the underlying `COM` control is painting on it's DC prior to the `WM_PAINT` message.

To workaround the issue, I wait for the window to show itself by waiting for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message, posting another application message which will then call `Invalidate()` and `UpdateWindow()`, thus forcing the redrawing of the window.

This technique is described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060925-02/?p=29603) on Raymond Chen's blog "The Old New Thing".

Answer (score -1):

Don't handle WM_ERASEBKGND.
Set WM_CLIPCHILDREN style on the dialog.

```
ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
...

BOOL CCalcDrillDownDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: So, I'm not sure what you are saying I am to do here.  If `OnEraseBkgnd() is called before OnPaint()`, then why would it not just paint the window after erasing it?  And why is it being erased?

Comment: In CDHtmlDialog, OnPaint() is ineffective to perform redraw.
Usually the html page will overlay the any drawing, so it cannot be redrawn.
Not enough info to prove it further.

Comment: Ok, so if this were the case, are  you saying to use `OnEraseBkgnd()` to use in place of `OnPaint()`?

Comment: What's the value of the .rc file (the local html file that it pointed to)?
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// HTML
//

IDR_HTML_CALC_DRILLDOWN_DIALOG    HTML     "???.html"

Comment: I've added the contents of the resource to the question.

Comment: If you wanted what was actually in the .rc file, it's `IDR_CALC_DRILLDOWN      HTML                    "RES\\CalcDrilldown.htm"`

Comment: Can you please Elaborate a bit more!?