# How to detour the main instance of a function?

Tags: winapi, detours

I'm trying to detour `::DrawText()` (and other draw text functions) for an application that has a lot of DLLs, some of which also use those functions.

I would have thought that if I detoured the main function using `DetourFindFunction()`, this would capture all cases from all functions in all DLLs, such that I could solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891357/why-would-a-dialog-erase-its-content-without-refreshing?noredirect=1#comment63240124_37891357) as there is text being displayed on the window.

Unfortunately, either `CDHtmalDialog` is somehow getting around the detour, or it is using some other function to draw the text on the window.

Could someone confirm that if I were to do this:

```
int (WINAPI *pDrawTextExW)(
  _In_    HDC              hdc,
  _Inout_ LPWSTR           lpchText,
  _In_    int              cchText,
  _Inout_ LPRECT           lprc,
  _In_    UINT             dwDTFormat,
  _In_    LPDRAWTEXTPARAMS lpDTParams
  ) = 0;

int WINAPI MyDrawTextExW(
  _In_    HDC              hdc,
  _Inout_ LPWSTR           lpchText,
  _In_    int              cchText,
  _Inout_ LPRECT           lprc,
  _In_    UINT             dwDTFormat,
  _In_    LPDRAWTEXTPARAMS lpDTParams
)
{
  return (*pDrawTextExW)(hdc, lpchText, cchText, lprc, dwDTFormat, lpDTParams);
}

CCalcDrillDownDlg::CCalcDrillDownDlg(/* bunch of parameters */, CWnd *pParent)
    : CDHtmlDialog(CCalcDrillDownDlg::IDD, 0, pParent)
{
  DetourTransactionBegin();
  DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
  pDrawTextExW = decltype(pDrawTextExW)(DetourFindFunction("user32.dll", "DrawTextExW"));
  DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pDrawTextExW, MyDrawTextExW);
  if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
    OutputDebugString("DrawTextExW() detoured successfully\n");
```

for each of `DrawTextA`, `DrawTextW`, `DrawTextExA`, `DrawTextExW` that if `CDHtmlDialog` were to use one of these functions to draw the text with, it would get detoured?  And perhaps someone would know how that class outputs text on the window's DC?

One funny thing that I did notice is that `DrawTextExW()` is getting detoured, trying to print the `OK` text on a button that is actually not displayed on the window.  Not sure what that's about.

```
>   cv32.dll!MyDrawTextExW(HDC__ * hdc=0x940111a2, wchar_t * lpchText=0x04925128, int cchText=2, tagRECT * lprc=0x012eb314, unsigned int dwDTFormat=1048613, tagDRAWTEXTPARAMS * lpDTParams=0x00000000) Line 4186   C++
    uxtheme.dll!CTextDraw::DrawTextW()  Unknown
    uxtheme.dll!DrawThemeText() Unknown
    comctl32.dll!Button_DrawThemed()    Unknown
    comctl32.dll!Button_DrawPush()  Unknown
    comctl32.dll!Button_PaintImpl() Unknown
    comctl32.dll!Button_WndProc()   Unknown
    user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()   Unknown
    user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
    user32.dll!DispatchClientMessage()  Unknown
    user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_DispatchMessageA@4()    Unknown
    mfc120d.dll!AfxInternalPumpMessage() Line 181   C++
    mfc120d.dll!CWinThread::PumpMessage() Line 900  C++
    mfc120d.dll!AfxPumpMessage() Line 190   C++
    mfc120d.dll!CWnd::RunModalLoop(unsigned long dwFlags=4) Line 4644   C++
    mfc120d.dll!CWnd::CreateRunDlgIndirect(const DLGTEMPLATE * lpDialogTemplate=0x7216cc28, CWnd * pParentWnd=0x012ecd60, HINSTANCE__ * hInst=0x6f730000) Line 470  C++
    mfc120d.dll!CDialog::DoModal() Line 633 C++
```

Comment: There's also `TextOut` and `ExtTextOut`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanPotter, I'll try those and see if I can get some results.

Comment: Unfortunately @JonathanPotter, although these functions are getting called, they are not getting called to render the text on the dialogue.  They are called when rendering text that isn't on the dialogue. o.O

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: "*I would have thought that if I detoured the main function using `DetourFindFunction()`, this would capture all cases from all functions in all DLLs...*" - no, not even close. Each DLL has its own imports table, and as such imports a given function independently of any other DLL importing the same function. `DetourFindFunction()` takes a binary name as input, it searches only one executable at a time. You would have to loop through the loaded DLLs manually, detouring each one individually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, hmm... yeah.  For some reason I thought that the memory was reused.  However, that doesn't sound right as a module could have state that my not wish to be shared between multiple instances. So, each DLL that references `user32.dll`, will actually load a separate instance of the `user32.dll` into memory?

Comment: @andlabs, as I said in my question, _"such that I could solve [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891357/why-would-a-dialog-erase-its-content-without-refreshing?noredirect=1#comment63240124_37891357)"_